# An easy positive riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

- A window with no glass
- A student with no class
- A sea in any season
- An epistle? No, a threesome

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*A window with no glass*

> A lens is like a window but the lens of an eye has no glass.

*A student with no class*

> Another word for student is pupil but the pupil of an eye has no class.

*A sea in any season*

> "A sea" sounds like "I see", which the eye does year round.

*An epistle? No, a threesome*

> Another word for epistle is letter. An eye is three letters.

The title: *An easy positive riddle*

> "Easy" sounds like "I see". Eye sounds like “aye”, a positive answer, the sí of the sea.

Comment: Hope you liked the riddle, the only thing I planned differently was the line about the sea

Comment: @Benthegeolologist Is this closer?

Comment: @Benthegeolologist: `A sea in any season` = rot13(eryngrq gb pelvat, ehaavat grnef sebz rlrf va nal frnfba?)